# Wire a property without a bean name?

Tags: spring

I need to wire a property for a given object without using a bean id, if possible. Autowiring doesn't work, because the type of the property is `Object` and is, hence, not specific at all.  Is there a way to autowire by class or interface like this:

```
<bean class="NonSpecificClassThing">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <a:wire-by-type type="com.things.MyInterface"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.things.MyInterfaceImpl"/>
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can do something like this :

target class :

```
public class NonSpecificClassThing {

      private Object targetObject;

      // do something;

      public getTargetObject() {
         return targetObject;
      } 

      public void setTargetObject(Object targetObject) {
         this.targetObject = targetObject;
      }
}
```

spring context :

```
<bean class="NonSpecificClassThing">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="com.things.MyInterfaceImpl"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.things.MyInterfaceImpl"/>
```

Comment: They reference the same object?

Comment: Can you provide a link to how this works? For instance, what if the `com.things.MyInterfaceImpl` bean is more configured?

Comment: @TK Kocheran I've edited my answer. What do you mean by more configured ? To have other bean injected into it ?